# CSS3 Animation not working in Chrome when called via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I have a footer with the following CSS:-

```
#transFooter {
opacity: 0;
margin-left: -2000px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes transFooter {
    100% { margin-left: 0; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes transFooter {
    100% { margin-left: 0; opacity: 1; }
}
```

It animates in with the following code:-

```
document.getElementById("transFooter").style.animation = "transFooter 2s forwards";
```

However, it doesn't seem to work on Chrome. Any ideas why?

Comment: animation doesn't work in chrome without prefix -webkit-

Comment: Where do I add said prefix? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, add:

```
document.getElementById("transFooter").style["-webkit-animation"] = "transFooter 2s forwards";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GMb3C/

Comment: Or 'document.getElementById("transFooter").style.webkitAnimation = "transFooter 2s forwards";'

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
document.getElementById("transFooter").style.webkitAnimation= "transFooter 2s forwards";
```